# ASPX, problem checkbox in header launch checkbox in next line

Tags: c#, asp.net

The checkbox in header check all chekbox (SelectAllCheckboxes), and a checkbox in each line (calculateAllCheckboxes).

When check the checkbox in header, the function calculateAllCheckboxes fires also.

How can I prevent that??

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemStyle Font-Size="3pt"></ItemStyle>
     <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" CssClass="CheckBoxClass" onclick="javascript: calculateAllCheckboxes(this);" runat="server" ></asp:CheckBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <asp:HiddenField ID="hiden" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("CodeMessage") %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
     <HeaderTemplate>
           <input id="chkAll" onclick="javascript: SelectAllCheckboxes(this);" runat="server" type="checkbox" />
     </HeaderTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

```
function SelectAllCheckboxes(spanChk) {
      var oItem = spanChk.children;
      var theBox = (spanChk.type == "checkbox") ?
           spanChk : spanChk.children.item[0];
      xState = theBox.checked;
      elm = theBox.form.elements;
 
      for (i = 0; i < elm.length; i++)
           if (elm[i].type == "checkbox" &&
               elm[i].id != theBox.id) {
               if (elm[i].checked != xState)
               elm[i].click();
           }
}
 
function calculateAllCheckboxes(spanChk) {
      var oItem = spanChk.children;
      var theBox = (spanChk.type == "checkbox") ?
             spanChk : spanChk.children.item[0];
      xState = theBox.checked;
      elm = theBox.form.elements;
 
      var total = 0;
      var montantTrim = "";
 
      for (i = 0; i < elm.length; i++) {
            if (elm[i].type == "checkbox") {
                 if (elm[i].id.indexOf("_CheckBox1") >= 0) {
                     if (elm[i].checked === true) {
                          var montantString = $("#" + elm[i].id).parent().parent().parent().children()[7].childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim();
                            montantString.replace(",", ".")
 
                          for (var j = 0; j < montantString.length; j++) {
                                if (montantString.charAt(j) != " ") {
                                    montantTrim += montantString.charAt(j);
                                }
                          }
                         total += parseFloat(montantTrim);
                    }
                }
           }
       }
       $("#montantTotal").text("Total : " + addThousandSpace(total.toFixed(2)));           
}
```

Comment: This code is C# not vb.net. I edited your tags.

Comment: It's on vb.net, aspx for c# and vb.net are the same.

Comment: Funny, isn't doesn't look a bit like any vb.net code I have ever seen.

Comment: the code above are in Aspx and Javascript.. but the project is on vb.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
elm[i].click();
```

Calling `click()` on a checkbox is equivalent to having the user click it, and so it calls the click event that you have set up for it.  Try this instead:

```
elm[i].checked = xState;
```

This updates the checkbox state without 'clicking' it, so the event won't be fired.

Comment: Thanks, Tawab. I did not pay attention.